# How to adress rerender in visualforce page on pageload

Tags: visualforce, picklist, rerender, actionfunction, images

I currently use the actionregion to rerender an image based on the input of a picklist field. This works by showing the image if I select the correct value in the picklist field. How do I  do an actionsupport on pageload to initialize the rerender? The Idea is to have 2 images from which 1 is shown on pageload and based on the picklist value selected the corresponding image is shown. See:

Panel:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="RenderImage">                         
                    <apex:image id="theImage4" value="{!$Resource.HR1}" width="200" height="200" alt="HR Ketel" rendered="{!Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c=='0'}"/><br/><br/>
              </apex:outputPanel>
```

Actionregion:

```
<apex:actionRegion >
                          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c}">
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="RenderImage" />
                          </apex:inputField>
                         </apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to do so; the initial state would be calculated based on the value in the field. If it's not working right, we'd need to see more code than you've shown here, ideally a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @sfdcfox I want to achieve this only from the input of the visualforce without info of the controller, or is this only possible with javascript?

Comment: You could set a default value on the field, or you can pass in a value as a page parameter, or you can use JavaScript. Any of the three might be appropriate depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who bumps into this I solved this the following way:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="RenderImage" style="margin-left:50px"> 
                    <apex:image id="ImageInit" value="{!$Resource.HR1}" width="200" height="200" alt="HR Ketel" rendered="{!NOT(Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c=='0' || Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c=='1')}"/>
                    <apex:image id="Image1" value="{!$Resource.HR1}" width="200" height="200" alt="HR Ketel" rendered="{!Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c=='0'}"/>
                    <apex:image id="Image2" value="{!$Resource.HR2}" width="200" height="200" alt="HR Ketel" rendered="{!Opportunity.StartRecurrent__c=='1'}"/><br/><br/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
```